# How to Check Photo DPI with PHP

Tags: php, resolution, dpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get/set DPI with PHP GD/Imagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076936/get-set-dpi-with-php-gd-imagick)

Is there a possible way to check photo dpi with php. I have 300 dpi and 72 dpi photos. but wants a way to calculate dpi automatically.

Comment: Found it for JPEG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262090/find-jpeg-resolution-with-php/262117#262117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too late for me to check now but I think you're looking for [`Imagick::getImageResolution()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimageresolution.php) and [`Imagick::setImageResolution()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setimageresolution.php) if you need to change the DPIs.

I don't think this is possible with GD, I believe it "converts" all images to 72 DPIs.

Answer (score 17):

If you want it `without Imagick or GD Library`.
I was struggling with this, and since I found it, here you go.

```
function get_dpi($filename){
    $a = fopen($filename,'r');
    $string = fread($a,20);
    fclose($a);

    $data = bin2hex(substr($string,14,4));
    $x = substr($data,0,4);
    $y = substr($data,4,4);

    return array(hexdec($x),hexdec($y));
}
```

and then print the array or do with it what you want.

Comment: Interesting input! But to which file types does this approach apply to?

Comment: it works for jpg format, look at denisb's comment at [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/5948-dpi-php-gd)

Comment: Hello there, I created a 300DPI JPEG via Photoshop, but the above function returns 42 DPI.