# Determine DPI for an Image with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

What is the fastest and easiest way to determine the DPI of an image in PHP using either ImageMagick or GD? Although it would be nice to determine the DPI of a wide variety of formats, at the very least, JPEG and PNG should be supported.

Similar questions:
[How to Check Photo DPI with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892731/how-to-check-photo-dpi-with-php)

[JPEG only solution](http://sandalian.com/php/get-dpi-value-of-an-image-using-php.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check Photo DPI with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892731/how-to-check-photo-dpi-with-php)

Comment: The question you linked to tells you exactly how...

Comment: Resolution (pixels) is not the same as DPI (dots per inch). I need to determine the real world printable size of an image which is Pixels/DPI = inches.