# How to get Image DPI in PHP

Tags: php, image, density-independent-pixel

I am searching for the code which could help me to get the Image DPI in PHP.

Could any one look into this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the image size (in px) scales with the dpi. you can print every picture with different dpi. the resulting image size (on paper) is just smaller the higher dpi goes. a pixel is always a pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go for some image libraries for that. Eg: Imagick, GD Library...

(OR)

You can use the following function,

```
function get_dpi($filename){
    $a = fopen($filename,'r');
    $string = fread($a,20);
    fclose($a);

    $data = bin2hex(substr($string,14,4));
    $x = substr($data,0,4);
    $y = substr($data,0,4);

    return array(hexdec($x),hexdec($y));
}
```

[Already solved this question here... :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892731/how-to-check-photo-dpi-with-php)

Comment: doesn't work for all images :( try image saved from cs3, blackberry, iphone, Kodak,..

Comment: good solution! thanks

Comment: it is get wrong dpi when image small it get 1 or 0 dpi if large image get 1072 dpi it is totally wrong

Answer (score 3):

I believe that doing a custom php won't convers all type of images.

The best way to install **Imagick**:

```
$image = new Imagick($filename);
$resolutions = $image->getImageResolution();
```

Comment: Autor was asking of DPI not image resolution.

Comment: Yeah, I've had mixed results with that. Still looking for something better. For me whether its 72 dpi or 300 dpi, it still returns 72 dpi.

Comment: @BlueMan DPI (Dots Per Inch) is resolution. No?.

Answer (score 2):

with ImageMagick

```
function getDPIImageMagick($filename){
        $cmd = 'identify -quiet -format "%x" '.$filename;       
        @exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd), $data);
        if($data && is_array($data)){
            $data = explode(' ', $data[0]);

            if($data[1] == 'PixelsPerInch'){
                return $data[0];
            }elseif($data[1] == 'PixelsPerCentimeter'){
                $x = ceil($data[0] * 2.54);
                return $x;
            }elseif($data[1] == 'Undefined'){
                return $data[0];
            }                       
        }
        return 72;
}
```

Comment: it gives perfect dpi but i need without use any librery