# Fetch DPI from JPEG without library returns incorrect result

Tags: php

I obtained a function that can read DPI value from JPEG [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12988682/188331).

```
function get_dpi($filename){
    $a = fopen($filename,'r');
    $string = fread($a,20);
    fclose($a);

    $data = bin2hex(substr($string,14,4));
    $x = substr($data,0,4);
    $y = substr($data,4,4);

    return array(hexdec($x),hexdec($y));
}
```

However, when I check an image created by Photoshop at 300DPI, it incorrectly returns the value of 42DPI.

[image: Photoshop CC screenshot]

What did I miss?

---

The problematic image generated by Photoshop: https://drive.google.com/open?id=117LHlgpefXZsuiVSl_nMG6MUQfKcT1MI

**UPDATE**: I tried an [online DPI converter](https://convert-dpi.com/) to regenerate the JPEG at 300DPI, the PHP function reports the correct value, 300DPI.

The regenerated image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-C4GZ8_K4wit3sISz21ngd4OVlLXuL72

I compared the metadata of 2 JPEGs, the generated JPEG has JIFF information, but the initial JPEG does not. Is that the cause of the problem?

*Given that I don't have Imagick library, I can't use its `getImageResolution()` function to read the value.*

Comment: Can you share the example image such that others can reproduce the problem?

Comment: updated in the question.

Comment: It can, because the header is in exif format. Maybe you can try to use `exif_read_data()`? http://www.latestcode.net/2013/01/read-php-exif-image-meta-data.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332823/retrieve-image-resolutiondpi-of-an-image-jpeg-png-svg-gif-without-using-any

Comment: If you can't use the prev. mentioned function and you still need to find out, than you need to read the exif specs.: https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html example program (not in php): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47486/Understanding-and-Reading-Exif-Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help from @golddragon007, my final solution is to combine data from various functions, as follow:

```
function get_dpi($filename){
    $new_filename = time() . '_' . rand(1000, 999999) . '.jpg';
    $result = move_uploaded_file($filename, 'upload/' . $new_filename);

    $dpi_from_exif = get_exif('upload/' . $new_filename);
    if($dpi_from_exif !== false) {
        unlink('upload/' . $new_filename);
        return $dpi_from_exif;
    } else {
        $a = fopen('upload/' . $new_filename,'r');
        $string = fread($a, 20);
        fclose($a);

        $data = bin2hex(substr($string, 14, 4));
        $x = substr($data, 0, 4);
        $y = substr($data, 4, 4);

        unlink('upload/' . $new_filename);
        return hexdec($x);
    }
}

function get_exif($filename) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    if($exif === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if(array_key_exists('XResolution', $exif)) {
            return do_maths($exif['XResolution']);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function do_maths($expression) {
    eval('$o = ' . preg_replace('/[^0-9\+\-\*\/\(\)\.]/', '', $expression) . ';');
    return $o;
}
```

Usage is as follow:

```
$dpi_in_int = get_dpi($the_image_file);
```

If I use the image I quoted in the question, the function will return:

```
300
```

Explanation of the function:

In my scenario, I read the uploaded file (from a `<input type="file" />`), the `get_dpi($filename)` first moved the temp upload file to the `upload/` folder (optional step), then read the DPI from EXIF using `get_exif($filename)` function.

If the DPI can be read from EXIF data, the DPI value will be returned; otherwise, the DPI value is fetched from the JPEG metadata (first few bytes of the JPEG file), which is proven inaccurate in some cases (e.g. the first image I supplied).

The `do_maths()` function is to parse the value from `XResolution` of EXIF's IPF0 data (which is `3000000/10000`, apparently a math equation) and calculate the final value. Please note that `eval()` has some potential security issues, therefore the input is first cleaned up with `preg_replace()` regex to ensure no injection code exists. This `do_maths()` function is from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805773/188331

Last, the `get_dpi()` function will delete the uploaded file to save disk space in server (optional).